Parallel, depth-first ops in Dagster with ops, graphs and jobs together
(also posted on r/dagster)
Dagster N00b here.
I have a very specific use-case. My ETL executes the following steps:

Query a DB to get a list of CSV files
Go to a filesystem and for each CSV file:


load it into DuckDB
transform some columns to date
transform some numeric codes to text categories
export clean table to a .parquet file
run a profile report for the clean data

The DuckDB tables are named just the same as the CSV files for convenience.
2a through 2e can be done in parallel FOR EACH CSV FILE. Within the context of a single CSV file, they need to run SERIALLY.
My current code is:
@op
def get_csv_filenames(context) -> List[str]:

@op(out=DynamicOut())
def generate_subtasks(context, csv_list:List[str]):
  for csv_filename in csv_list:
    yield DynamicOutput(csv_filename, mapping_key=csv_filename)

def load_csv_into_duckdb(context, csv_filename)

def transform_dates(context, csv_filename)

def from_code_2_categories(context, csv_filename)

def export_2_parqu


If I understand correctly, you want depth-first processing, instead of breadth first? I think you might be able to trigger depth-first processing using a nested graph after the dynamic output step. You're also conceptually missing how to set dependencies between ops in Dagster. Something like this should work:
@op
def get_csv_filenames(context) -> List[str]:

@op(out=DynamicOut())
def generate_subtasks(context, csv_list:List[str]):
  for csv_filename in csv_list:
    yield DynamicOutput(csv_filename, mapping_key=csv_filename)

@op
def load_csv_into_duckdb(context, csv_filename)
  ...
  return csv_filename

@op
def transform_dates(context, csv_filename)
  ...
  return csv_filename

@op
def from_code_2_categories(context, csv_filename)
  ...
  return csv_filename

@op
def export_2_parquet(context, csv_filename)
  ...
  return csv_filename

@op
def profile_dataset(context, csv_filename)
  ...
  return csv_filename

@graph
def process(context, csv_filename:str):
  profile_dataset(export_2_parquet(from_code_2_categories(transform_dates(load_csv_into_duckdb(csv_filename)))))

  
@job
def pipeline():
  csv_filename_list = get_csv_filenames()
  generate_subtasks(csv_filename_list).map(process)


Doesn't work. It still launches the functions in process in parallel. Like, it is launching export_2_parquet even before the DuckDB db file is created in the load_csv_into_duckdb function. Care to share some more ideas?

@JesusRamos - oh you have to declare dependencies between the ops - in your case you could just return csv_filename from each op onto the next one. I'll fix the example shortly

thank you for the pointers. before reading your fixes, I tried the soft dep approach, with @op(ins={In(Nothing}} for all individual tasks, and then chaining the call to each of them like you show in the example (although more verbose, with var assignment and passing it), and it worked alright. Do you know if there's a difference between the hard dependency approach and the one with Nothing deps in the decorator?

@JesusRamos the main different is whether the outputs are stored / loaded by an IO manager between steps. If you don't want to use an IO manager you can use Nothin dependencies all day. However, IO managers provide a really nice abstraction that makes it much easier to test your ops, and to potentially switch storage services, for instance if you want to store things locally when testing on your laptop, but in the cloud when running in production.

Ok, cool, can confirm both hard and soft deps approaches work. Thanks for the assist, man! Much appreciated! Didn't measure running times, but I also felt tasks started more immediately with hard deps.
